# Ruby: validate URL

Tags: ruby, url

A teacher presented me with a problem that must be solved in Ruby:

> "Write a function that allows for checking whether a given string starts with the correct determination
>   of protocol in the URL. The correct name for the protocol consists of 3 to 5 lowercase letters,
>   followed by a sequence “://”. Use the regular expressions.

After hours of googling I had no success. Basically, I need the exact thing that the problem asks: I need to check if a given string contains the sequence "://" and if it does, I need to check if has 3 to 5 lowercase letters before the sequence.

With the help of Amadan this is what I've come up with:

```
def check_url(url)
pattern = %r{\A[a-z]{3,5}://}
if pattern.match(url) != nil
puts "TRUE"
else
puts "FALSE"
end
end

print "Input an URL: "
new_string = gets.chomp

check_url(url)
```

Comment: Which specific part is giving you the trouble? The answer is so easy, saying anything is basically solving homework for you. What have you tried? Did you try some regular-expression-specific help, like http://regular-expressions.info/ and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html ?

Comment: The part that troubles me is checking what does the string contains before the "://" sequence if it is found. My code so far only checks if string contains "://" using include? method.

Comment: `.include?` is not a regular expression method. Given that the task specifically directs you to use regular expressions, a good start is to read the two webpages that I linked, which should give you the good foundation for solving the problem.

Comment: I have my reasons why this task is not an easy one for me. I will read the webpages you linked from A to Z. Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion: use the `%r{}` syntax to bypass the need to escape the slashes.

Comment: It might not be easy for you; it is objectively easy (if write it just so, the core of the solution is about 19 characters long). Boiling an egg might be difficult if you have zero experience with cooking, but it doesn't mean it's not the simplest thing when compared to actually cooking a proper meal.

Comment: Ok, I'm stuck here... I've read the webpages you provided numerous times and I'm struggling to write a decent pattern. So far I've come with the following pattern:
`pattern = %r{\A([a-z]{3,5} + "://")}`

Comment: Almost! :) Regular expressions are not strings, no need for concatenation. Thus, `%r{\A[a-z]{3,5}://}` is what you want. (What you actually wrote is: start of string, then 3-5 lowercase letters, *then one or more spaces, a quote, a colon, two slashes and another quote*. For example, a matching string would be `http    "://"`).

Comment: Ok, the pattern part finally gives no errors, but whatever string I input, the output is "FALSE". Here's the whole code:
`def check_url(url)
pattern = %r{\A[a-z]{3,5}://}
if pattern.match(url) != nil
    puts "TRUE"
else
    puts "FALSE"
end
end

print "Input an URL: "
new_string = gets.chomp

check_url(url)`

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read (and you didn't put any in :D ) Just edit your main question and append the code there.

Comment: So, you input your string in `new_string` but test `url`?

Comment: Thanks, man, you're my saviour... I guess I had too much Ruby today :D

Comment: Perhaps next time, play around in www.rubular.com with the required matches to evolve the solution you are looking for. You may learn a thing or two.